# Extracting genome from a Ciphertext

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, number-theory, machine-learning

Cryptography is the practice of securing communication from unauthorized access. One way of securing information is through encryption, where plaintext (clear text) is transformed into ciphertext using a complex algorithm. The ciphertext is designed to be indistinguishable from random data and difficult to reverse without the key. However, could there be any characteristic patterns in ciphertext that can be visualized, similar to how a microscope can reveal tissue from ground meat?

In other words, is it possible to extract the "genetic code" of a ciphertext and visualize it in a complex image, like the human genome? If so, what methods and techniques could be used to identify and visualize these patterns?

Previous research has been focused on securing and making encryption algorithms irreversible without having the key. But is it possible that new discoveries in number theory or other methods could lead to finding characteristic patterns in ciphertext that were previously unknown?

Ultimately, the question is whether there are any identifiable patterns or characteristics in ciphertext that could reveal information about the original message or encryption algorithm, despite being designed to be indistinguishable from random data.

Converting this:

```
60AD5A78FB4A4030EC542C8974CD15F55384E836554CEDD9A322D5F4135C6267
A9D20970C54E6651070B0144D43844C899320DD8FA7819F7EBC6A7715287332E
C8675C136183B3F8A1F81EF969418267130A756FDBB2C71D9A667446E34E0EAD
9CF31BFB66F816F319D0B7E430A5F2891553986E003720261C7E9022C0D9F11F
```

To this:

[image: ciphers genome]

Comment: define genome. if there is an idea it is hard to tell. also you probably mean 'ciphertext' not cipher (the encoding scheme)

Comment: A human genome is not randomized **on purpose** though, and a butcher will likely be able to guess the meat type without a microscope (color, smell, fat structures etc.), so there the analogies break down.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what analogy would you choose, for comparing plaintext to ciphertext procedure?

Comment: Well, maybe we can do without analogy here; I'm not sure that the internal structure of a  (symmetric) cipher is present anywhere in nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take the question as:

> Is it possible to analyze ciphertext (encrypted with a large unknown key) and thus distinguish characteristics of the plaintext, like we can sequence minced meat and deduce information about the original meat?

Not for proper encryption. By definition of that, [the only characteristic of the plaintext that can be distinguished from the ciphertext is size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability). Working meat analogy: mass. How can that be? A semi-working analogy would be that proper encryption minces down to 0/1 bits (proton/electron particles, in an hypothetical universe where that's the only two kinds).

Not all encryption is proper, though. For some kind of defective encryption, there are ways to find plaintext characteristics from ciphertext. E.g., for a cryptosystem combining [poly-alphabetic substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalphabetic_cipher) and [transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher), we can find from the ciphertext the ratio of frequency of the most frequent to second most frequent plaintext symbols, because encryption conserves that quantity.

Also, encryption is proper with respect to a certain level of technology. Some ciphers that are proper against the unaided human brain are not against a computer. Some ciphers that are proper against classical computers might not be against quantum computers usable for cryptanalysis, that with enough imagination might become reality rather than hype.